# Lepton 3.5 thermal camera image quality issue [running on Jetson Nano]

Tags: opencv, camera, video-capture, v4l2, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am using Lepton 3.5 with Pure-thermal 2. Compiled C + V4l2 code on Jetson Nano from Groupgets git page: https://github.com/groupgets/purethermal1-uvc-capture.

Initially got this error message Libv4l didn't accept RGB24 format. Can't proceed. Then changed image resolution from 80x60 to 160x120 and pixel format YUYV to UYVY then the code works but not generating good images. The image contains multiple strips having different colors as shown below:

[image]

Changing pixel format to GREY and resolution 640*480, generated the image shown below:

[image]

Please anyone suggest how to get the perfect images in GREY, UYVY and other supported formats.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <linux/videodev2.h>
    #include <libv4l2.h>
    
    #define CLEAR(x) memset(&(x), 0, sizeof(x))
    
    struct buffer {
            void   *start;
            size_t length;
    };
    
    static void xioctl(int fh, int request, void *arg)
    {
            int r;
    
            do {
                    r = v4l2_ioctl(fh, request, arg);
            } while (r == -1 && ((errno == EINTR) || (errno == EAGAIN)));
    
            if (r == -1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
            struct v4l2_format              fmt;
            struct v4l2_buffer              buf;
            struct v4l2_requestbuffers      req;
            enum v4l2_buf_type              type;
            fd_set                          fds;
            struct timeval                  tv;
            int                             r, fd = -1;
            unsigned int                    i, n_buffers;
            char                            *dev_name = "/dev/video0";
            char                            out_name[256];
            FILE                            *fout;
            struct buffer                   *buffers;
    
            fd = v4l2_open(dev_name, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
            if (fd < 0) {
                    perror("Cannot open device");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }       

            CLEAR(fmt);
            fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
            fmt.fmt.pix.width       = 640;
            fmt.fmt.pix.height      = 480;
            fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_GREY;
            fmt.fmt.pix.field       = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;
            xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt);
            if (fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat != V4L2_PIX_FMT_GREY) {
                    printf("Libv4l didn't accept RGB24 format. Can't proceed.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if ((fmt.fmt.pix.width != 80) || (fmt.fmt.pix.height != 60))
                    printf("Warning: driver is sending image at %dx%d\n",
                            fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);

            CLEAR(req);
            req.count = 2;
            req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
            req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
            xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req);
    
            buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));
            for (n_buffers = 0; n_buffers < req.count; ++n_buffers) {
                    CLEAR(buf);

                    buf.type        = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                    buf.memory      = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                    buf.index       = n_buffers;
    
                    xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf);

                    buffers[n_buffers].length = buf.length;
                    buffers[n_buffers].start = v4l2_mmap(NULL, buf.length,
                                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                                  fd, buf.m.offset);

                    if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[n_buffers].start) {
                            perror("mmap");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i) {
                    CLEAR(buf);
                    buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                    buf.index = i;
                    xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf);
            }
            type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;

            xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type);
            for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    do {
                            FD_ZERO(&fds);
                            FD_SET(fd, &fds);
    
                            /* Timeout. */
                            tv.tv_sec = 2;
                            tv.tv_usec = 0;

                            r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                    } while ((r == -1 && (errno = EINTR)));
                    if (r == -1) {
                            perror("select");
                            return errno;
                    }
    
                    CLEAR(buf);
                    buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                    buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                    xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &buf);

                    sprintf(out_name, "out%03d.ppm", i);
                    fout = fopen(out_name, "w");
                    if (!fout) {
                            perror("Cannot open image");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    fprintf(fout, "P6\n%d %d 255\n",
                            fmt.fmt.pix.width, fmt.fmt.pix.height);
                    fwrite(buffers[buf.index].start, buf.bytesused, 1, fout);
                    fclose(fout);

                    xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &buf);
            }

            type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
            xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type);
            for (i = 0; i < n_buffers; ++i)
                    v4l2_munmap(buffers[i].start, buffers[i].length);
            v4l2_close(fd);
    
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the usb descriptor?
the purethermal firmware creates an uvc device and with lsusb you can get a list of the supported formats and frames in the usb descriptor.